# How can I use Caliburn to check a method by default after an event?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro XAML framework.  I have a `Button`, and I need to check after every click whether it should remain enabled => every click removes one object from collection and when it is empty, button have to become disabled.

The Can method checks is automatically, but it checks it only during window loading. I need to check it after every single click over and over again.

Specifically, after every click I need to check whether `ObservableCollection.Count > 0` and if not, then disable this `Button`.

XAML View:

```
<Button x:Name="AddRecord" IsEnabled="{Binding CanAddRecord}"/>
```

C# ViewModel:

```
public bool CanAddRecord()
{// debugging does not go here, thats the PROBLEM i need to solve
    return Collection.Count > 0
}
public void AddRecord()
{// here it is OK, debugging goes here properly
    Collection.Add(someObject);
}
```

QUESTION: Is there some elegant way with using Caliburn to check the `CanAddRecord` method by default, after every button click?

NOTICE: I try to avoid PropertyChanged events and things like that. Because it denies Caliburn principle.

Comment: Sure, bind the Button's Command property.

Comment: No, it does not works.

Comment: Where is this `CanMethod`? How it's implemented? Are you firing the `PropertyChanged` event when the value of `CanAddRecordProp` changes? "but it checks it only during form loading", Form? Is this a Windows Forms code or WPF code? You mean page right?

Comment: Mahmoud: I am sorry, the question was not good, i will try as hard as i can to ask much better next time. I updated it a bit now.

Comment: @user7968180 The issue was you still need to notify WPF that it should check `CanAddRecord`. You mentioned avoiding `PropertyChanged`, but that is how you must notify the framework at times, just as the answer demonstrates. Now it will hit your breakpoint when you debug. Before it was never checking `CanAddRecord` after the first time and it did not know it needed to check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding the `IsEnabled` property, you should add a `CanAddRecord` property to your view model and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for this one in your `AddRecord()` method:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> Collection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();

public void AddRecord()
{
    Collection.Add(1);
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanAddRecord));
}

public bool CanAddRecord => Collection.Count == 0;
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="AddRecord" Content="Add" />
```

This should disable the `Button` when an item is added to the source collection.

Caliburn.Micro is all about conventions. Since the `Name` property of your `Button` is set to "AddRecord", the framework will connect it to the `AddRecord()` method and the `CanAddRecord` property of the view model for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Absolutely excellent!!! You are a man, you helped me a lot, thanks!